# General Question about transferring Solution from containers (Workplace Related)

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solutions, safety

At my workplace we will soon begin diluting a solution to specific concentrations, this is done within a specific container.

The solution to be diluted is provided by a manufacturer in the following type of bottle :

[image]

The contents inside this bottle can only be retrieved with a syringe. However, we need to transfer volumes in the ranges of $ 0.015 \,mL - 0.06 \,mL $  ,with syringes we cannot be confident (because we have to eyeball it real hard).

So we think of course to transfer from the bottle to a beaker and then using a micropipette to transfer to the desired container and dilute. The problem is that the solution to be diluted is extremely expensive , and every unnecessary transfer to a beaker will cause some of our solution to be lost , beakers need to be also washed THOROUGHLY if they are to be reused.

Question : Are there any viable instruments that have a needle to enter the bottle and enough accuracy to transfer $ 0.015 \,mL - 0.06 \,mL $ ? Can you think of any way we can get around our problem?. We hope we can do just 1 transfer from Manufacturer bottle to our desired container to be diluted. Upon researching online we have not had much luck.

- Opening , and replacing the cap of Manufacturer bottle gives problems with sterile properties of solution , as well of greatly reduces the expiry date.
- Transfering from manufacturer bottle to beaker and then micropipetted to desired container to be diluted , gives rise to problems of sterile , as well as time consuming due to having to thoroughly clean the beaker, causes loss of solution.

I know this question may not be appropriate for this site , but I do thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Do you have Hamilton syringes? That is the way, along with appropriate use of them.

Comment: @Alchimista these look promising! they are a bit in the expensive side but i suppose there's not much that can be done , thanks for the input! Have to check cost vs earning to see if they are worth it.

Comment: Yes, they are expensive and requires proper operation and care.